# How to pop history of a tab from parent tabs component in ionic v2

Tags: ionic2

I have three tabs as follows:

```
<ion-tabs>
     <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
     <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" (ionSelect)="goToPreviousPage()" tabTitle="Back" tabIcon="arrow-back"></ion-tab>
     <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" (ionSelect)="goToNextPage()" tabTitle="Next" tabIcon="arrow-forward"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

So tab 1 loads the main content and the other two tabs are for navigating the app. Here is the tabs component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  tab1Root: any = HomePage;
  tab2Root: any;
  tab3Root: any;
  navCtrl;

  constructor(navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.navCtrl = navCtrl;

  }
  goToPreviousPage(){
   // Need logic to navigate back in history for Tab 1
  }

  goToNextPage(){
    //Logic to navigate forward in Tab 1 content
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the NavController for Tab1 so as to navigate it's history, or is there a way to get component for tab 1, so as to call methods defined within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not really what the tab layout is intended for. When using tabs, each tab has it's own history stack. But in your case, you only seem to use one history stack and want to navigate forward and backwards on that. So my suggestion would be to instead not use the tab navigation, but just one page and then put a tab-bar into the footer of the page. Then you can assign (click) methods to the tabs.

However, I'm not sure if this is good design. I have never seen an app that used this kind of tab-navigaton. People will expect the default tab behaviour and will be confused when it behaves otherwise. What are you trying to do exactly? What is the workflow of your app?

I would start with a new, blank project and start from there. `ionic start myApp blank --v2` Maybe you could also use a side menu for navigating to different parts of your app.

Comment: Thanks!! I have a one page with ion-toolbar, and placed the navigation buttons within the toolbar. To answer your question: I'm creating a simple app to show some guide, and so users navigate through it to read the content.